# Reading char* with gets() makes "Core Dumped" error (C language)

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault, coredump

I'm trying to read a user input with a non-fixed char array, but it just *soft crashes* (no crash window) when I input something on the keyboard. When I run it on an online C compiler, that's when its says *Segmentation fault (core dumped)*.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int validerNAS(char* userInput);

int main() {
    int valid = 0;
    char* userInput;

    do {
        printf("Enter 9 characters: ");
        gets(userInput);
        valid = validerNAS(userInput);
    } while (!valid);
    return 0;
}

int validerNAS(char* userInput) {
    if ((strlen(userInput) != 9))  {
        printf("Error! You must enter 9 characters\n\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you expect input to get stored? You haven't allocated any memory. Other than that - don't ever use `gets`, it is not a part of the language anymore and being deprecated.

Comment: `char* userInput;` -> `char userInput[100];`. Read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book.

Comment: And there is a small but obvious bug in `validerNAS`, I'll let you find out by yourself.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. I tried using scanf("%s", userInput) but it does the same error.

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s", userInput)`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  In this case, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.  2) when using the input format  specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]' always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}`  this results in the function ALWAYS returning 0.  Suggest the second `return` statement return 1

Comment: The function: `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely removed for several years.  You compiler should have told you that.  Suggest using `fgets()` (read the MAN page as it has a different set of parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
char* userInput;
```

`userInput` doesn't have any valid memory so that you can put some data into it like

```
gets(userInput); /* this causes seg.fault because till now userInput doesn't have any valid memory */
```

So to overcome this problem either use character array like

```
char userInput[100] = {0};
```

or create dynamic array and then scan the data into dynamically allocated memory.

Also don't use `gets()`, use `fgets()` instead as stated in [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/gets.3.html)

For e.g

```
char* userInput = malloc(SOME_SIZE); /* define SOME_SIZE, creating dynamic array equal to SOME_SIZE  */
fgets(userInput ,SOME_SIZE, stdin) ; /* scan the data from user & store into dynamically created buffer */
```

Side note, from the manual page from [fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)

> If a **newline** is read, it is **stored into the buffer**. A
>   terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in
>   the buffer.

So remove the trailing new line character by calling `strcspn()`. For e.g

```
userInput[strcspn(userInput, "\n")] = 0;
```

And once usage of dynamic array `userInput` is done, don'tr forget to free the dynamically allocated memory by calling `free()` to avoid **memory leakage**. For e.g

```
free(userInput);
```